# Indefinite integration of $\frac{\exp(x)}{\sqrt(x)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $\frac{\exp(x)}{\sqrt(x)}$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: If you mean $\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}~dx$,the result contains a non-elementary function ([Imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=t^{2}$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx &= 2 \int \mathrm{e}^{t^{2}} dt \\
&= \sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{erfi}(t) \\
&= \sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{erfi}(\sqrt{x}) + C
\end{align}
where
$$\mathrm{erfi}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{z} \mathrm{e}^{t^{2}} dt$$
is the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, hypergeometric:
$$
\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}\;dx = 2\,\sqrt {x}\;{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\,x\right)} + C
$$